# Talend for big data hadoop 2.2.0

Tags: hadoop, talend

I am using Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 64 bit platform. I did not find connectivity of this Hadoop version in Talend for Big Data 5.6 Studio.
Can anyone please guide me how can I connect with apache hadoop 2.2.0?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue after spending many hours. Below steps are needed to follow to support Talend with Apache Hadoop 2.2.0.

I am using Talend 5.6 for Big Data in Windows 8.1

1. I compiled Apache Hadoop 2.2.0 in windows 8.1 environment
2. Then set HADOOP_HOME with C:\hadoop in Environment Variable.
3. Use Cloudera cdh5.1 Yarn Mode ( which supports Hadoop 2.2.0) or you
   can use Custom UnSupported option as well from Talend Hadoop cluster connection.
4. Then create connection and select custom connection from repository
   Type.
5. You can make seamless connection with your Hadoop 2.2.0 environment.